# Unable to open the wordpress website getting http error

Tags: wordpress

```
[14-Sep-2018 07:00:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(/home/website/public_html/learn/wp-includes/embed.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/website/public_html/learn/wp-settings.php on line 201
[14-Sep-2018 07:00:57 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/website/public_html/learn/wp-includes/embed.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php71/usr/share/pear') in /home/website/public_html/learn/wp-settings.php on line 201
```

Getting this error while trying to open the website which is developed in wordpress.This is the sub domain which we created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the embed.php is missing in the given directory . did you check it ?